# Syncing Mechanism Works Perfectly on Local Machine, But Deletes All Videos on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have a mechanism that runs on startup that will delete any orphaned data.  It walks through a mongodb collection of videos and checks to make sure it can match a record in the db to the corresponding file on disk.   If it finds an orphaned record it deletes it.   It then flips around and walks the directory to make sure all files found have a matching record in the db.

When I run this on my local machine, it works flawlessly.   However, each time I do a deploy to heroku and my dyno restarts, the entire 'video' collection gets deleted.

I did some rudimentary testing, after creating a video in Heroku, it's in the database and available for download.   My GUESS is Heroku doesn't like something about fs.access.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
walkVideos: function() {
    // First let's lookup videos and make sure there is a directory for them.  If not, delete it from the db.
    Video.find().exec(function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return null;
      }
      if (result.length === 0) {
        console.log('No videos found in db');
        return null;
      }
      _.forEach(result, function(video)  {
      // make sure I can access the style file.
        fs.access(scormifyConfig.videoBasePath + video._id + '/dist/' + video._id + '_' + video.filename + '.zip', function(err) {
          if (err && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            //Can't find the style file, i need to delete it
            Video.remove({_id: video._id}, function(err, result) {
              if (err) {
                console.log('Error removing video from the db');
              }
                if (result) {
                  console.log('Out of sync video pruned from the db');
                }
              });
            }
          });
        //  console.log('Matched video from DB to disk.   No action.');
      });
    });
    // let's walk the other way and make sure all videos found on disk have a match in the db at the folder level.
    fsp.traverseTreeSync(scormifyConfig.videoBasePath,  // walk through the content directory
       function(file) {
      },
    function(dir) {
      let _id = dir.replace('content\\videos\\', '');  // on dir, trim to just the id.  this can be matched to the DB _id field.
      Video.find({_id: _id}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        if (result.length === 0) {  // didn't find the video.
          console.log('video found on disk, but not in the db.   Removing from disk.');
          fs.removeSync(scormifyConfig.videoBasePath + _id, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          });
        }
        //console.log('Video matched from disk to DB.   No action');
      });
    },
      function() {
    console.log('done checking videos.');
  });
  }
```

**EDIT**

I did some additional debugging.  I am still not sure why this is occuring, it looks like it should work.

```
Jul 14 14:40:37 scormify app[web]  { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access './content/videos/5787f91a9332950300d85ad4/dist/5787f91a9332950300d85ad4_da-dka-dlk-lsk.zip']
Jul 14 14:40:37 scormify app[web]   errno: -2,
Jul 14 14:40:38 scormify app[web]  Out of sync video pruned from the db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynos have what Heroku call an 'ephemeral filesystem'. In other words it's not persistent across deploys. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

So what you are seeing is normal behaviour albeit highly inconvenient for you right now. The reasoning behind it is that a filesystem local to a dyno wouldn't scale when you start to increase the number of dynos that your app is running. It also breaks the principle that dynos are disposable.

The recommended alternative is to store files like your videos on another service better designed for the purpose, e.g. Amazon S3.